# Hard Join in Magento

Tags: magento, join

i am a beginner Magento Developer and i have a difficult task to add in a grid a special column.

The column is named Type RMA. I made the sql query but i need to translate it in Magento my query is:

```
 SELECT t1.*, (t3.total_qty_ordered - t2.qty_requested) as 'type_rma' 
FROM enterprise_rma_grid as t1 
JOIN enterprise_rma_item_entity as t2 
ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id 
JOIN sales_flat_order as t3 ON t1.order_id = t3.entity_id;
```

So in my  `_prepareCollection()` i have something like these :

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->join();
```

And i have no idea how to translate my SQL code in a magento one. My goal is to add the values calculated above as a new column named "type_rma", and display it in my grid  as:

```
$this->addColumn('type_rma', array(
            'header'  => Mage::helper('enterprise_rma')->__('Type RMA'),
            'type'    => 'options',
            'width'   => '100px',
            'index'   => 'type_rma'
        ));
```

Thanks in advance for all your ideas and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after 10 hours of searching...

```
$collection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                array('t2' => 'enterprise_rma_item_entity'), 'main_table.entity_id = t2.entity_id',
                array('type_rma' => new Zend_Db_Expr("(t3.total_qty_ordered - t2.qty_requested)")
                )
            )->join(
                array('t3' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'main_table.order_id = t3.entity_id',
                array()
            );
```

Comment: Just need to read more carefully the documentation on magento, and with the use of the printLogQuery(true) function i solved it.